# Sending JSON to parse.com using request body

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

I am sending a post request in Android to parse.com and need to include the headers and body in a single json object as the post request body.
Is this possible like this (most likely not since I get error message from parse.com response:

```
{
"headers": [
    {
"Content-Type":"application/json",
"X-Parse-Application-Id":"key1",
"X-Parse-REST-API-Key":"key2"

"body": [
    {
        "ephrase": "When the going gets tough, the tough get going.",
        "nvote": 154,
        "pphrase": "Meaning2",
        "yvote": 364
    },
    {
        "ephrase": "Beggars can't be choosers.",
        "nvote": 1,
        "pphrase": "meaning1",
        "yvote": 8
    }
] }
```

If this is not going to work, I am trying the following but still get an error "107 invalid utf-8 tsring was provided" from parse.com

I include this in header section of the picture:

```
"Content-Type":"application/json",
"X-Parse-Application-Id":"key1",
"X-Parse-REST-API-Key":"key2"
```

And this in the body section where parse.com expects a json object

```
{ [
    {
        "ephrase": "When the going gets tough, the tough get going.",
        "nvote": 154,
        "pphrase": "",
        "yvote": 364
    },
    {
        "ephrase": "Beggars can't be choosers.",
        "nvote": 1,
        "pphrase": "",
        "yvote": 8
    }
] }
```

[image]

Comment: From where are you sending this request? What client are you using to make this call?

Comment: You have posted wrong json struct above. please sure it is extractly

Comment: Why do you need to send the keys in the header? Those should be secret to your application.

Comment: Parse requires you to send your keys in the header

Answer (score 1):

Adding headers in the body is not good practice, headers needs to be sent separately.

If you are using HTTPPost to send the request then you can add the headers using addheader function

```
httppost.addHeader("YOUR-KEY", "YOUR-value");
```

in your case this will be

```
 httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
 httppost.addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "key1");  
 httppost.addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "key2");
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Headers are not part of the JSON body. Headers are separate part of the request. Only the body content should be part of the json you send.

Comment: I have a small code whch also allows me to include separate headrers and bod, would you guys know how that may work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend u to use HTTPURLConnection instead of other deprecated apis.

```
    String urlStr = "";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url1;
    String jsonBody = "{ [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"ephrase\": \"When the going gets tough, the tough get going.\",\n" +
            "        \"nvote\": 154,\n" +
            "        \"pphrase\": \"\",\n" +
            "        \"yvote\": 364\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"ephrase\": \"Beggars can't be choosers.\",\n" +
            "        \"nvote\": 1,\n" +
            "        \"pphrase\": \"\",\n" +
            "        \"yvote\": 8\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "] }";

    try {

        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonBody);

        url1 = new URL(urlStr);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", "key1");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "key2");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.connect();

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
        osw.write(jObj.toString());
        osw.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Just make sure u do above things inside AsyncTask's doInBackground() or a thread will just be fine.

Comment: Please remove this answer if you are not looking to solve the problem seriously.

Comment: @Amir: I may have misunderstood ur Q. Wts goin wrong could u plz tell me?

Comment: @Amir: Did it helped u?

Comment: Going for new year fireworks :)  will let you know tomorrow.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found this sample that has all types of HTTP:

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http

If you are using this you need to add the following code to JsonStreamerSample.java to allow you including Headers.

```
public boolean isRequestHeadersAllowed() {
    return true;
}
```

I still have a small problem though which is further explained in the question below.

[Passing JSON object to parse.com in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543970/passing-json-object-to-parse-com-in-android)